# Use Pictures from another website as SharePoint profile pictures

Tags: sharepoint, profile

We have a "corporate directory" website that displays some contact information about our employees. Among other things like displaying data from Active Directory, it also displays a picture, which can be retrieve via a URL of the format http://[CorpDir]/PersonPhoto.aspx?email=[UserEmail]

I'm now looking for a way to use these pictures as profile pictures in SharePoint, as easy as possible. Custom coding for SharePoint is not an option for us at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set the PictureUrl property for each user profile. Even if you can't add custom code on the server to do that, you can probably write code elsewhere that uses the web services to set the profile.

You may also be able to do it with customization of the out of box AD import - take a look at the settings for that and what you have available in AD.